# How to persist DataFusion DataFrame in memory

Tags: apache-arrow-datafusion

How can you persist a DataFusion DataFrame in memory with the Python bindings?  From what I understand, DataFusion doesn't persist data in memory by default.

Here's how I register a CSV as a table:

```py
import datafusion

ctx = datafusion.SessionContext()
ctx.register_csv("x", path)
```

How can I persist this data in memory?

Comment: I filed a feature request to add this to the Python bindings - https://github.com/apache/arrow-datafusion-python/issues/20